# AngularJS optional login

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I'm trying to figure out a way to make logging in optional. So basically, I still want to keep the existing access option with user login id and password, but also another option that the user can click on a link that takes them directly to the page without having to log in.

Is there a way to do this with AngularJS?

Comment: Which router are you using? `ngRoute` or `UI-router`?

Comment: I believe it is ngRoute. I just want a general idea on how I would be able to implement this.